# Adding row to query based on results from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table called tblUsers with user information and another table called tblBadgesEarned with nm relation to tblUsers containing an entry for every badge earned by a user.

If I get the a users information from tblUsers I would like the result to include a field called "BadgesEarned" for example that is an array of all the badges earned by said users from tblBadgedEarned.

Is it possible doing this in a single query or do I have to split it up and add the field to the array result afterwards?

Comment: It is possible.  But since that's all the information you give, that's all in answer I can give.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish something like this using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Here's a sample query based on the minimal schema information you provided:

```
select tblUsers.username, 
  group_concat(distinct tblBadgesEarned.badge_name order by tblBadgesEarned.badge_name)
from tblUsers
  left outer join tblBadgesEarned on tblBadgesEarned.user_id = tblUsers.id 
group by tblUsers.username;
```